# Animation opacity doesn't stay in Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, css-animations, polymer

I've made a basic polymer-element that acts as a wrapper for fading things in and out based on the state of the data-binding for it's visibility attribute.

The logic is simple. Visibility == true ? fadeIn : fadeOut.

The problem is that once the animation completes the elements opacity resets.

**Why does the elements opacity reset to 1 after the animation?**

Code below:

```
<link rel="import" href="core-animation/core-animation.html">
<polymer-element name="page-fader" attributes="visibility">
    <template>
        <style>
            :host {
                display: inline-block;
                background: white;
                width: 100%;
                height: 100px;
                content: "";
            }
        </style>
        <content> </content>
    </template>
    <script>
    Polymer('page-fader',{
        visibility : false,
        fader : {},
        start : 1,
        stop: 0,
        observe : {
            visibility : function() {
                this.visibility ? this.fadeIn() : this.fadeOut()
            }
        },

        ready : function() {
            this.fader = new CoreAnimation();
            this.fader.duration = 1000;
            this.fader.keyframes = [
              {opacity: this.start},
              {opacity: this.stop}
            ];
            this.fader.target = this;
        },

        fadeIn : function() {
            console.log( this.id + " in" )
            this.start = 0;
            this.stop = 1;
            this.fader.play();
        },
        fadeOut : function() {
            console.log( this.id + " out" )
            this.start = 1;
            this.stop = 0;
            this.fader.play();
        },

    });
    </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want the animation's effect to continue with the final value after the animation has ended then set `fill` to `"forwards"`.

Docs: http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/elements/core-elements.html#core-animation

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how is the fill "forwards" implemented. But after animation, I cannot change that property with JavaScript anymore... It makes that css property "read-only"...

Comment: Yes I would like to reset the style properties after a several animations but cannot with javascript. @cn123h you ever solve this?